# MySQL Error 5154: Invalid placeholder (Node.js XDevAPI Connector)

Tags: mysql, node.js, nosql

I'm currently using a MySQL server (version 8.0.12) and connecting to it with the official Node.js MySQL connector which supports XDevAPI and NoSQL. I'm trying to pull some blog posts from the database, but am getting error 5154.

Here is my code:

```
// Data used
const postsPerPage: number;
const start: number;

let results: BlogPost[] = [];

await blogPosts
    .find('accountID = :accountID')
    .bind('accountID', req.account.id)
    .sort('posted ASC')
    .limit(postsPerPage + 1)
    .offset(start)
    .execute(post => {
        results.push(post);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that `req.account.id` was actually undefined at this point. My input data was a bit messy